# how to configure both mongodb and postgres in spring boot application.yml?

Tags: spring, mongodb, postgresql, spring-boot

We have spring boot project , in which we need to use mongo and postgres , but i thought am failing in configuring mongo and postgres details applicaiton.yml , below my what i configured , can any one please help me

```
spring:
    profiles: stage
    data:
      mongodb:
        host: mongodb-host
        port: 27017
        password: password
        username: username
        authentication-database: database
        database: database
    datasource:
        driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
        url: postgres-url
        username: user-name
        password: password
        tomcat:
          validation-interval: 30000
          test-on-borrow: true
          validation-query: SELECT 1
```

when i start my spring-boot application , it is failing to start with below error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName.
```

can any one please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1:  remove `spring.datasource.driver-class-name` property

Solution 2: rename the `spring.datasource.url` property to `spring.datasource.jdbc-url`.

For solution 1 Spring Boot will figure out the default driver class name based on the spring.datasource.url property value.

Comment: thanks a lot , i have chosen solution 1 , and it worked .May i know in my case exception happened previously ?

Comment: because Hikari has no url property (but does have a jdbcUrl property)..Spring Boot will figure out the default driver class name based on the spring.datasource.url

Comment: one more problem am facing now , server startup taking too much time ,when i started the spring boot app , it stuck their at "[  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect" any idea ?